# Error: Certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, command, certificate

I hope sb could help me. I got an error  `certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate` when I'm installing the module. Then I click the **Install Certificates.command** file in the python3.8 folder, it shows another error of

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I know that I can add user in the last(e.g. pip3 install module --user), but this is the one to click the files, not typing the command. Then how to do it?

In the below if the code, it shows

```
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 24, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

But I don't know what does it mean.

I expect there are some solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It tells you in the error message that you quoted that you could add the parameter "--user" when running the command, in case you're doing this from the command line.

Another thing that you could try is to run this as Administrator, you shouldn't get any "Permission denied" errors anymore then.